# ActionSheetOption Example?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement where i am suppose to design a pop-up window with some icons, for example share  button which will open a small window from the bottom which holds list of all social network platforms along with their icons.I am using Xamarin Forms and need to do this for iOS and Android.

I am using the nuget developed by Allan Ritchie, Acr UserDialogs and came across DisplayActionSheet as one of the option, just want to know if anyone has an working example of the same.

[image: This is what i am trying to acheive]

Also if someone has an example of uploading audio/video files using Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without library

```
    <RelativeLayout>
    <StackLayout 
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" 
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}"> ... </StackLayout>  //Put here your main layout

    <StackLayout x:Name="ActionSheet"
RelativeLayout.YConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,  Constant= 100}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}" >

// Your action sheet items

</StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your Page class:

```
void ShowActionSheet()
{
ActionSheet.TranslateTo(-100);
}

void HideActionSheet()
{
ActionSheet.TranslateTo(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Response, but cant it be possible using the Acr.UserDialog nugets Display Action Sheet Method.?